# How to Execute CURL POST with PHP and Local Node Blockchain?

Tags: php, node.js, curl, post, blockchain

I have my localnode from the blockchain running in `localhost:4444` and I want to make this cURL question to the node when I press a button in PHP.
This is my code when I press a button but it doesn't work.

Thanks!!

```
function blockNumberConsulta()
{   


    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'localhost:4444',
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
        'jsonrpc' => '2.0',
        'method'  => 'eth_blockNumber',
        'params'  => '[]',
        'id'      => '1'
    )));
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));

    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    echo $resp;

// curl localhost:4444 -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_blockNumber","params":[],"id":1}'
}
```

Comment: what does `curl_error()` give you? http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

Comment: have you tried using `postman` or a similar tool?